# How do I share variables between different imported files?

Tags: sass

I want to use SASS in a modular way. In the code segment below you can see a way I consider organizing some of the layouts of a page.

What I have in mind is the [external variables in languages like C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c).

```
// file: some_page.scss  
//   
// I want some variables from the fonts, colors partials  
// to be visible to the buttons partial  
// Is it possible?   
// error: _buttons.scss (Line X: Undefined variable: "$color_blue")

@import "colors"  
@import "fonts"  
@import "buttons" 

// in file: _colors.scss  
$color_blue: blue;

// in file: _buttons.scss  

.button {
    background-color: $color_blue;
}
```

Comment: This should just work. I use this on all my projects without any problems. If you are seeing an error, something else is going wrong.

Comment: this still doens't work for me. it seems avariables need to be inside the file that using it.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias How do you know that "the error was unrelevant to the actual question"?  If the OP neglected to include the semicolon, then the question should have been closed as a typographical error.  If the semicolon is present, then the question should still be closed as "not reproducible".

Comment: @cimmanon the syntax error in the example code was unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias And fixing the syntax error does not produce the error claimed in the question.  In fact, it doesn't produce an error at all.

Comment: I just had same problem in Visual Studio using Web Essentials. A minute later it started working. I used Ctrl-Z on my files to try to go back to what wasn't working but couldn't get it to break again no matter what I tried. So I think it was just a quirky thing with Visual Studio or Web Essentials.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, that's how it works.

As long as `_colors.scss` is imported before the other files.

You can check out the port of Twitter Bootstrap to Sass here: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass it uses variables in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a `;` at the end of the `@import` line.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: It's the solution. I ran into the same problem.

Comment: Ok, You mean, when a semi-colon is added then the variables are shared? Wow, That seam highly non-intuitive. On which line should it be added the "sharer" or the "receiver"? do you have a reference to it?

Comment: Not true if the file extension is .sass

Comment: @Ben That is true, but the question says `some_page.scss`. I ran into this exact problem myself. Here is the documentation. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: @Chloe Indeed. That's why my statement is a comment on your answer, and your statement is an answer ;)